# Show a modal before leaving page with react-router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have been using **react-router v6** And having issues to block the user navigation.
Can't use the **Prompt** component as it has been removed in **v6**
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#prompt-is-not-currently-supported

How can I block the user navigation and show the modal for confirming the navigation?

Comment: You may be able to create a custom router and history object and use [`history.block`](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#historyblockblocker-blocker) in combination with an `useEffect` hook's cleanup function or `beforeunload` window event handler.